# Length of an interval (very basic)

Tags: real-analysis

This is perhaps a stupid question.

I read a definition of the length, $|I|$, of an interval :

$|I| = (\sup I) - (\inf I)$

I thought the length was the difference between the "input values"/traditonally x-axis-values of the interval (for instance the interval $[1,3]$ would have length 3-1 = 2).

But it could also be the difference in "output values"/traditionally y-axis-values. (for instance if if you take $f(x) = 2x$: $[1,3] \to \mathbb{R}$ it would be: $|I| = (\sup I) - (\inf I) = 3\cdot2-2\cdot1=4$)

Which one is it?

Comment: The image of $f:[1,3] \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x) = 2x$ is $[2,6]$. $[2,6]$ is different from $[1,3]$. These intervals have different lengths.

Comment: The length of an interval obviously only should depend on the interval itself, not some random function.

Comment: By the classification of intervals, we only have 4 types of nonempty bounded intervals, namely $(a, b)$, $(a, b]$, $[a, b)$ and $[a, b]$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a < b$. Now what is $\sup (a, b)$, $\inf (a, b)$, $\sup (a, b]$, $\inf (a, b]$, $\sup [a, b)$, $\inf [a, b)$, $\sup [a, b]$ and $\inf [a, b]$ respectively?

Comment: Also, it might be useful to note that we say $M = \sup I$ if and only if $M$ is an upper bound for $I$, i.e. $\forall x \in I$ $x \le M$ and $\forall \varepsilon > 0$ $M - \varepsilon$ is not an upper bound for $I$, i.e. $\forall \varepsilon > 0$ $\exists x_0 \in I$ such that $x_0 > M - \varepsilon$. We have similar definition for $m = \inf I$ as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have misunderstood the notation: $\sup I$ is the supremum of the interval $I$. So, if the interval is $I =[1,3]$, $\sup I = 3$.

The definition in your question would give a length $3-1=2$ if the interval is $[1,3]$. (In your parlance, "input value".)

It is a whole different matter if you are interested in the length of the range of a function. In your example, the very same definition would give you a length of $6-2=4$, but this is only because you apply it to the (range) interval $I=[2,6]$.